# Cannot open saved File in Django Admin

Tags: django, file, http-status-code-404, admin

I can succesfully save a file via Django admin in one of my models but cannot open the file aftewards. Here is my model:

```
class Answer (models.Model):
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    attach_file = models.FileField(upload_to='Attachments', blank=True)
```

I have not touched the settings file and to my understanding it should use defaults values:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''
STATIC_ROOT = ''
```

I registered the model in the admin.py and I was able to Browse a file and save it. When trying to open that file, i get:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/businessui/answer/1/Attachments/outlook.png/
answer object with primary key u'1/Attachments/outlook.png' does not exist.
```

Could someone point out what I am missing here to be able to also open saved files locally on my dev machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reference to @Sawwy's comment on @RicardoCarmo's answer.  I post as an answer for the formatting.

Here's what I use in my main url conf:

```
if getattr(settings, 'DEBUG', False) or getattr(settings, 'DEBUG_MEDIA', False):
    media_url = getattr(settings, 'MEDIA_URL', '/media/').lstrip('/')
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % (media_url,), 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT
        }),
    ) + urlpatterns
```

Note that in a production environment, your media files should be served up by the web server and those requests should not reach Django. That is why it's qualified with `if DEBUG or DEBUG_MEDIA`.

Comment: Thanks @RicardoCarmo and @dokkaebi! Both replies included information that was required for solution. Unfortunately I cannot mark them both for answer... I was aware that I will need to figure out the production side environment correctly but I am currently working on the very first iteration and just wanted to get it working on my local machine.

Also, I'm getting good excerise as python/django newbie in going through your code examples to learn why the admin files now work as they do :)

Answer (score 5):

Try to set your settings.py like this:

```
import os
PROJECT_ROOT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT_PATH, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

So, try to get your file in:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/Attachments/outlook.png
```

Comment: Got a bit further and it seems I am missing media related conf in urls.py file:

"Using the URLconf defined in MyProject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:...

"The current URL, media/Attachments/outlook.png, didn't match any of these."

I don't have any r'^media/' or similar lines in my urls.py at the moment.